# How to transfer a variable within a funtion in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I'm running **km_test.sql** from a bat-file (Windows 7):

```
call psql -h ... -U ... -d ... -f C:\svn\tre2\prog\km_test.sql -v nrl=%a%
```

where %a% is an integer. I'm running on PostgreSQL 9.5.

**km_test.sql** looks like this

```
\set n :nrl

DROP FUNCTION km_test(integer);
CREATE FUNCTION km_test(n integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   j smallint;

BEGIN
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS km_test CASCADE;
   CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE km_test (
     lnr smallint,
     km_id character varying(16),
     flatenr smallint,
     geo geometry(Linestring,25833)
    );
  j = 1;
  WHILE j < n+1 LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Verdi j er : %', j;
    INSERT INTO km_test (lnr, km_id, flatenr, geo)
      SELECT d.i,
             p.km_id,
             CAST(substring(p.flatenr from 5 for 4) AS smallint),
             ST_MakeLine(p.geo,(ST_Translate(p.geo, d.dx, d.dy)))
      FROM org_tre2.km_punkter_des2016 AS p, org_tre2.km_dxdy1 AS d
      WHERE j = d.i;
    j = j + 1;
  END LOOP;
  COMMENT ON TABLE org_tre2.km_test IS 'KM innsyn: n innsynslinjer for kulturminnepunkt utenfor IK i tre2-flater';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

\set tab 'org_tre2.km_punkter_des2016'
select km_test(:n);
```

**Question:** How do I make table p (org_tre2.km_punkter_des2016) to be an input parameter? Meaning how to include the tablename in the function-call (with select km_tull(:n,:p)) and refer to this table within the function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION km_test(n integer, t text)
...

select km_test(:n,:'tab')
```

So far I have not managed to refer to the input-table as the t-variable in the FROM-statement.
Is it possible? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Take a look at Dynamic commands. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Thanks for the link @mcNets. I think I've figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hint/link @McNets. I think I've figured it out. Correct code in **km_test.sql**:

```
\set n :nrl

DROP FUNCTION km_test(integer, text);
CREATE FUNCTION km_test(n integer, t text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   j smallint;
   s integer;

BEGIN
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS km_test CASCADE;
   CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE km_test (
     lnr smallint,
     km_id character varying(16),
     flatenr smallint,
     geo geometry(Linestring,25833)
    );
  j = 1;
  WHILE j < n+1 LOOP
    s:=j;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Verdi j er : %', j;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Tabell t er : %', t;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO km_test (lnr, km_id, flatenr, geo)
      SELECT d.i,
             p.km_id,
             CAST(substring(p.flatenr from 5 for 4) AS smallint),
             ST_MakeLine(p.geo,(ST_Translate(p.geo, d.dx, d.dy)))
      FROM '||t||' as p, org_tre2.km_dxdy1 AS d
      WHERE '||s||' = d.i';
    j = j + 1;
  END LOOP;
  COMMENT ON TABLE org_tre2.km_test IS 'KM innsyn: n innsynslinjer for kulturminnepunkt utenfor IK i tre2-flater';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

\set ptab 'org_tre2.km_punkter_des2016'
select km_test(:n,:'ptab');
```

The solution being using EXECUTE, put all the INSER INTO-code within '', declare s as a variable and use s instead of j in the WHERE-clause.